# I want create like left side images but it show like right side view?

Tags: html, wordpress, css

[image: i want to create like left side but show like right side]
problem is that all css need in only one div Because theme is not allow me to create an "parent-child div" in wordpress

My code is Like

```
.bg{
background-repeat: no-repeat;
background-image: url(http://godiaperfree.codelessme.net/wp-content/uploads/2014/06/elimination-communication-photo.jpg) rgba(170,242,114,0.5);;
background-attachment: scroll;
background-position: bottom center;
}


<div class="bg">My text</div>
```

And Also, is it's possiable to make all css in one div Because theme is not allow me to create an "parent-child div" in wordpress

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like the rgba(170,242,114,0.5) is causing the whole layer to become 0.5 transparent.

Either remove the transparency (edit the image instead), or put the text in a layer outside the div and position it on top of the transparent layer (either with position or a negative margin-top).

Comment: hi Richard thanks for reply, these are two options i could not take.. are there any other option instead?

Comment: Why can't you take them?

Comment: can't edit image, cause my client specifically told me to use css and for the other option i have to give negative margin, which'll destroy responsive structure..

Comment: What was the reason for not editing the image?  You could generate a 50% transparent version of the image using PHP and so not have to touch the original image.

Comment: You wouldn't have to necessarily use negative margin, either.  Using position:absolute and position:responsive could work, though would require more divs. (See here: http://css-tricks.com/absolute-positioning-inside-relative-positioning/ )

Comment: One other potential solution: if the image is fading onto a white background, then create a 0.5 opactity white png and set this as a background in a new layer on top of the image layer, but behind the text. This should look the same but doesn't require the image to be edited or the div to have any opacity set.

Comment: You could have just put a span inside the div, removed the opacity from the div and put it on the span and then positioned everything correctly and it would work much better than using another image taking up more bandwidth... too late now you've accepted another answer but example here: http://codepen.io/anon/pen/mxLjw

Comment: Yes, that is a better solution than the image one.  I was assuming that the transparency causing the problem on the outer div would also cause a problem on any inner element. I see from your demo that it does not.

Answer (score 1):

Try to put the text outside the "div" tag. The best would be if you put it before it.